# UIToolbar and UINavigationBar not hiding on setHidden:YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm using storyboards and I've referenced the storyboard and I'm getting a value back using my Storyboard ID.

[image: Storyboard document outline]

[image: NavigationController Storyboard ID]

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
```

This is done within the `UIViewController` `-viewDidLoad:` method that's currently at the root of the `UINavigationController` hierarchy.

[image: NavigationController inspector view]

In the storyboard I've chosen to show both the `UINavigationBar` and `UIToolbar` associated with `UINavigationController`. I then set them to hidden in my code for the hell of it:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = navigationController.navigationBar;
[navigationBar setHidden:YES];
UIToolbar *toolbar = navigationController.toolbar;
[toolbar setHidden:YES];
```

but they're still visible! Why the heck are they still visible? Stepping through the code tells me that these variables have a non-nil value. Furthermore, I would obviously get a run-time error if they were nil.

I have also tried the methods on `UINavigationController`:

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
```

These don't work either.

I would like to note that the program doesn't crash. It just glides over these methods with no warnings. Checking the state of these "bars" indicates that they are in fact hidden (using `isNavigationBarHidden` and `isToolbarHidden` on `UINavigationController` instance) but this isn't apparent in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

problem was instancing the `navigationController` and assigning it to a local variable instead of accessing it through the embed navigation controller property of a UIViewController

Problem solved

Comment: I've tried inside both `-viewDidLoad:` and `-viewWillAppear:`

Comment: sorry misread that part, so are you instancing your `navigationController` inside a `viewController -viewDidLoad:` and setting the `viewController navigationController`?

because if so, the `self.navigationController` is a read-only var

you need to set the `rootViewController` of the `navigationController` as the `viewController` you want

Comment: I'm getting the reference for the `NavigationController` in the storyboard and storing that reference inside my `UIViewController` so I can reference it later from any of its methods. I'm not calling the `init` command anywhere.

Comment: self.navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];

that call doesn't work

Comment: I don't follow. I'm not assigning my view controller to the navigation controller. It's done in storyboards and my view shows up just fine. If I were trying to assign something to a read-only variable, I would get a compile time warning and a run time error.

Comment: self.navigationController is my own variable. Not an API's. I've changed the name to self.navController to confirm this. I have even made this a local variable to the method.

Comment: I see now, your property has the same name of that is usually reserved for the `viewController navigationController`, but since you said your controller is initialized in your storyboard with that view as root or inside it's navigation hierarchy, why set another property for it?  

all `viewControllers` has access of it's `navigationController` through the self.navigationController property.  
 
edit: saw the last asnwer now

Comment: Thank you. Yes, referencing self.navigationController without having to call `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` solved the issue. I can't recall why I thought it to be necessary to call this method in the first place.

Comment: you're welcome, it happens =D

edited my answer trying to resume the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64209/discussion-between-alex-smith-and-renato-neves).